# Mysql - select rows which have linked values

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the bad title, do not know how to describe it in one sentence.

There is the table:

```
id, user_id, task_id
```

I need to select user_ids which have records with several task_id
Kind of pseudocode

`Select user_id from tasks wherehas task_id = 1 and task_id = 2`

Comment: Where task_id in (1,2)

Comment: ^^ that solution is better, but just so you are aware, you can also do `WHERE (task_id = 1 OR task_id = 2)`

Comment: Maybe my explanation is not clear. I need to select if has one `AND` another, not `OR`

Comment: So the users who have both a task_id 1 AND a task_id 2?

Comment: @JeremyHarris, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they say, there are many ways to skin a cat. Here is one:

To get a list of users that have multiple tasks assigned, and (at minimum) they have task_id 1 AND task_id 2:

```sql
SELECT 
   user_id
FROM user_tasks // or whatever your table is called 
WHERE task_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT task_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us get all the rows where task is is 1 or 2, group them up by user and show only users who have a min task ID that is different to the max task id:

```
SELECT 
 user_id
FROM t 
WHERE task_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MIN(task_id) <> MAX(task_id)
```

You need to appreciate in all of this that when you write a WHERE clause, it is evaluated to be true for every individual row. This means you cannot say `WHERE x = 1 AND x = 2` because the value of X can never ever be simultaneously 1 and 2 ON THE SAME ROW.

Instead we use an OR, to get all the user rows that are 1 or 2 and this will give us a mix - some users have multiple rows (the first row is 1 and the next row is 2). Other users have only one row- either a one or a two.

```
User Task
John 1
Jane 1
Jane 1
Jake 1
Jake 2
Joel 2
```

When we apply a grouping operation, all those rows are squashed down to one row per user and then things like MIN and MAX can be used and make sense. For a user with only one row his MIN and MAX will be the same number. For a user who had 20 rows that are all value 1, they will also be MIN and MAX the same. Only users who have at least one row that is a 1 and another row that is a 2 will have a different min and max:

```
User MIN MAX
John 1   1
Jane 1   1
Jake 1   2     <-- the only user HAVING MIN <> MAX
Joel 2   2
```

Min and max is only really useful in cases where you're looking for 2 different values. In other cases you might look for COUNT DISTINCT that contains the same number as there are elements in the IN list

Comment: `This means you cannot say WHERE x = 1 AND x = 2` I know about it, what's why I wrote `pseudocode`, will it work with 3 or more `task_id`?

Comment: See the final comment- if you want to make sure a user has 3+ then it's of the form `WHERE x IN (a,list,of,things) GROUP BY y HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT x) = number_of_things_in_the_list` - in this case the IN contains 4 things and the count distinct should be 4

Comment: (Note that you shouldn't put duplicate values in the list) - `WHERE x IN (1,2,2,3,4)` should have a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT x) = 4` not 5 (there are 4 unique things in the IN list. This might be obvious but I did want to mention it if you're getting values from a table

Comment: MIN/MAX will only ensure that the user has at least two different values; if you had IN(1,2,3) then minmax could give you users that had 1/2 only. It's important. To understand limitations of each approach

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want the values of user_id for which there is a task with task_id 1 and a task with task_id 2.

Your solution doesn't work because it's looking for a task which has task_id 1 and task_id 2 (which is impossible)

You need:

```
select a.user_id from tasks a where a.task_id = 1 inner join 
    tasks b where b.user_id = a.user_id and b.task_id = 2
```